# How to implement DEMO release

Tags: version-control, versioning, git-flow

My team and I are using GitFlow to versioning our code, but now we need to have a third branch for DEMO to be able to

- publish from DEVELOP in DEMO for testing and then from DEMO to MASTER when all tests are passed
- merge a fix from DEMO to DEVELOP
- merge a hotfix from MASTER into DEMO and DEVELOP at the same time

here is a draft of the versioning flow (I hope it helps):

[image]

I can't find a solution with GitFlow, any advice? Should we choose another tool?

Answer (score 1):

This problem sounds like it has arisen as a result of deployment processes, not Git merging strategy.

There is no concept of a `demo` branch in GitFlow, though it sounds like you're essentially trying to make use of a `release` branch. It's worth noting that there is nothing in GitFlow itself to regulate exactly how you *deploy* any of your branches, and the choice of whether or not to use GitFlow should be made independent of your server architecture.

What it sounds like you're looking for is to deploy out a `release` branch to an independent testing *server*, then test against that. Once the tests pass, you can deploy the *same commit* (on the `release` branch) out to the production server. This way you don't need to worry about a separate branch specific to testing. Note that `master` itself should not be deployed to production; it is merely considered a 'reference' to the last known stable version of the code. You should be merging back to `master` straight after a deployment (and tagging the commit) in case you need to revert back to the target version in the future.

This is illustrated in the standard Git Flow shown below:

[image: GitFlow]

To take this a step further, there is also a DevOps testing concept of [shifting-left](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shift-left_testing), where the `develop` branch *itself* is what is tested against, and considered to be shippable in itself. This simplifies the process even further, and there are pros and cons to choosing such an approach. It may be worth considering after evaluation.

Comment: Clear but, as far as I think, having 3 different branches (belonging to 3 different state of code) might be easier to manage: **the stable version (currently MASTER)**, **the likely next version (DEMO)** that needs to be tested and that a team keeps on developing because requests change or become clearer using the application, and finally **the even later version of the code (DEVELOP)** that needs to be update from DEMO passively because who are working on it are focused on developing new requests and don't need to worry about past ones. Thank in advance for you help.

Comment: @EmanueleLacopo when I read your question, I immediately thought your `DEMO` branch sounds just like a Git Flow `release` branch. Even after reading your comment here I still don't see how you feel `DEMO` differs from a `release` branch?